# show multiline data in rich text box

Tags: c#

how to show data in multiline in rich textbox from database table? I set the rich textbox property ".Text" and also set "multiline=true". But rich text box show only on row of data tabel's column.this one code i am using. i am using windows form application first time.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {

            OleDbConnection connstring = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\MyTablesDB.mdb");
            OleDbDataAdapter dadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Table where id=" + comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "+1", connstring);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            dadapter.Fill(dset);
            if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                richTextBox2.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
                richTextBox3.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();

            }
            else
            {
            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: Please do not create a new question, but just add the code by editing the previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896307/show-data-in-multiline-form-in-rich-textbox-from-database#18896307

Answer (score 1):

```
richTextBox1.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
richTextBox2.Text += dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
richTextBox3.Text += dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

or a short method

```
public void BoxaddLine(string toAdd)
{
    rchtxtbox.Text = rchtxtbox.Text + Environment.NewLine + toAdd;
}
```